# Fundamental theorem of arithmetic - usage of Euclids lemma

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I was reading the proof for of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic on wikipedia, but when they prove the uniqueness, I got stuck. The proof starts like this:

> Assume that $s > 1$ is the product of prime numbers in two different ways:
>
> $$\begin{aligned}s&=p_{1}p_{2}\cdots p_{m}\\&=q_{1}q_{2}\cdots q_{n}.\end{aligned}$$
>
> We must show $m = n$ and that the $q_j$ are a rearrangement of the $p_i$.
>
> As $p_1$ divides $s$, Euclid's lemma implies that $p_1$ divides one of the $q_j$ [...]

(*[from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Uniqueness)*)

I'm familiar with Euclids lemma, if a prime $p | ab$, this implies $p | a$ or $p|b$ (or both). But I can't make the mental leap to understand why this implies that $p_1$ divides one of the $q_j$. Can someone add more explanation?

Comment: It's an unstated use of induction: if you have $k$ numbers, you can write their product as $AB$, where $A$ is the first number and $B$ is the product of the $2$nd through $k$th. Euclid's lemma tells us that either $A$ or $B$ is divisible by $p$; if it's the former, we're done, while in the latter case we can repeat the argument for the $k-1$ numbers in $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you have just said it...  $p|s $ and $s=q_1q_2\cdots q_n $, therefore by repeated application of Euclid's lemma we are done... (you actually apply the lemma $n-1$ times )

Answer (score 3):

$p_1 \mid q_{1} \cdot (q_{2}\cdots q_{n}) \implies p_1 \mid q_1\,$ or $\,p_1 \mid q_{2}\cdots q_{n}\,$. If $\,p_1 \mid q_1$ then you are done, else it means that $\,p_1 \mid q_{2}\cdots q_{n}\,$, then repeat the same step for $p_1 \mid q_2 \cdot (q_3 \ldots q_n)$.